# SOAP Client php

Tags: php, soap, webservice-client

I'm need a little help about WS SOAP Client in PHP.

I have a WS SOAP, restrict to my IP, but I don know almost anything about SOAP, I've already use SOAP with rails a long time ago.

If I access the SOAP server from my browser using this: http://thedomain.com/wssitedsv/site.asmx/RetornaGanhadores

The server return me the correct XML.

If I access the SOAP server from my browser using this:
http://thedomain.com/wssitedsv/site.asmx?wsdl

The server return a xml with configuration of the SOAP

In the PHP I'm doing it:

```
$url = "http://thedomain.com/wssitedsv/site.asmx?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($url);
$return = $client->RetornaGanhadores(NULL);

echo $return;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /Users/sidnei/Sites/suasorte/scripts/get_data.php:15
\\nStack trace:
\\n#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://192.168....', 'https://www.tte...', 1, 0)
\\n#1 /Users/sidnei/Sites/suasorte/scripts/get_data.php(15): SoapClient->__call('RetornaGanhador...', Array)
\\n#2 /Users/sidnei/Sites/suasorte/scripts/get_data.php(15): SoapClient->RetornaGanhadores(NULL)
\\n#3 /Users/sidnei/Sites/suasorte/index.php(2): include('/Users/sidnei/S...')
\\n#4 {main}
\\n  thrown in /Users/sidnei/Sites/suasorte/scripts/get_data.php on line 15
```

I can get all methods from Server using this:

```
$url = "http://thedomain.com/wssitedsv/site.asmx?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($url);
$return = $client->__getFunctions();

print_t $return;
```

What I am doing wrong to use this SOAP server?

How use a SOAP Server in PHP?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: give me the correct url

Comment: Just use `file_get_contents('http://thedomain.com/wssitedsv/site.asmx/RetornaGanhadores');` if it already returns the correct xml.

Comment: @subroutines and if I need pass variables to other methods? How can I do it?

Comment: @sidneivl you can try appending query strings to the url, such as `http://thedomain.com/wssitedsv/site.asmx/method?variable_name=value`